# Read xml and make clickable listview

Tags: xml, android-listview, xml-parsing

Hi everybody I need some help to get this working:)
What I want to do is to make every row in this listview clickable.
Example: When I click on  Name1 I want it to collect the rest of the items(2-3) and make that visible in a new window.
Note: I have not yet collected the information that is suppossed to be shown in the next window. Right now I'm just intressted in to be able to go to "next window" to show information for item1-3. How to make this happen?

I'm reading and parsing a local XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data-set xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <record>
        <item1>Name1</item1>
        <item2>1</item2>
        <item3>2746</item3>
    <record>
        <item1>Name2</item1>
        <item2>2</item2>
        <item3>3842</item3>
....whatever
....whatever    
....whatever (Note it is a very long xml file with a lots of records and items)
```

My XML parse code:

```
ArrayList<String> myarraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
....whatever
....whatever    

while(type != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if(type == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
    }
    else if(type == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        nameSTARTTAG = parser.getName();
    }
    else if(type == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        if(parser.isWhitespace())
        {
        }
        else if(nameSTARTTAG != "record"&& nameSTARTTAG != "data-set" && nameSTARTTAG != "null")
        {
            ItemInfo = parser.getText();
            if(nameSTARTTAG.equals("item1"))
            {
                myarraylist.add(""+ nameSTARTTAG + ": " + ItemInfo);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(type == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
    }
    type = parser.next();
}
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, myarraylist);
mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
```

Mylistview:

```
 <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/mainListView"
     android:clickable="true">
 </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hell yeah I found a way:)
This did the trick:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
        long arg3) 
{
    String name = arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
}
});
```